# Restart after - Install certificate on Azure webrole

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-roles

Is there a way to install a new certificate on an already running web service without the need to restart/redeploy the IIS/service?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so because the information about the certificate is stored in both `csdef` and `cscfg` file and `csdef` file gets bundled into the package file. Based on this information and the certificate you uploaded under the cloud service certificates section, Azure Fabric Controller installs the certificate in appropriate certificate store when the role is created.

One hacky way you could try (**and is certainly NOT recommended**) is by connecting to your cloud service VM using RDP and install the certificate manually. Even though you could do it as a temporary reprieve but it is certainly not recommended because of the stateless nature of cloud services. If for some reason Azure Fabric Controller decides to create a new VM or you decide to scale out (i.e. add more instances), the certificate information is taken from existing package file which will not have your latest certificate.

Comment: We did something similar, added a code in the service that on event installs the certificate "manually" from the DB. But it still requires some module restart.

Comment: Note that a cloud service architecture which doesn't allow for somewhat arbitrary restarts of roles is probably flawed from a service perspective.